# Need help Copying and Editing sheet within the same Spreadsheet in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need some help refining this code. It should copy a specific worksheet in this case the sheet Master Copy based on the rows on the sheet Maxes. Then rename the sheet to the name on the given row in the sheet Maxes.  When I try to execute the code all it does is insert a blank page and adds it to the end of the Spreadsheet. Please forgive the poorly written code I am really new at this and trying to make something work. Any suggestions that you could give would be gratefully appreciated. I'm not sure if there is an error within the while loops or what exactly.

```
function createWorkouts(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var nameSource = ss.getSheetByName("Maxes");
var nameColumn = nameSource.getRange("A2:A300");
var nameStartRow = nameSource.getRange("A2");

var trainingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master Copy");
var trainingRange = trainingSheet.getRange("a1:m66");

var nameEndRow = nameSource.getLastRow();
var lifterName;


while (nameStartRow <= nameEndRow)
{
 lifterName = nameSource.getCell(nameStartRow, nameColumn);

 if (lifterName == null)
 {
  errors.clear();
  ss.getSheetsByName(lifterName) = lifterName;
  if(errors.number() > 0)
  {
    errors.clear();
    var newSheet = ss.insertSheet();
    ss.renameActiveSheet(lifterName);
    ss.getSheetByName(lifterName);
    trainingRange.copyValuesToRange(lifterName,1,1,16,66);
    lifterName.copyValuesToRange(lifterName,4,1,4,1);
   }
  } nameStartRow = nameStartRow + 1;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modifyed your code because I didn't understood what you wanted exactlly, I hope this will do the trick:

```
function createWorkouts(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var nameSource = ss.getSheetByName("Maxes");
  var nameColumn = nameSource.getRange("A2:A").getValues(); // it's a table of table [][]

  var trainingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master Copy");
  var trainingRange = trainingSheet.getRange("A1:M66").getValues(); // get values give a table of table

  for(var i in nameColumn){ 
    if(nameColumn[i][0]!=""){ // if blank we skip
      try{ // try to see if already exist who know...
        var lifter = ss.getSheetByName(nameColumn[i][0]).activate();
        Logger.log("getting lifter sheet "+nameColumn[i][0]);
      }
      catch(err){ // well it didn't exist so lets create it :D
        var lifter = ss.insertSheet(nameColumn[i][0]);
        Logger.log("creating lifter sheet "+nameColumn[i][0]);
      }
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      lifter.getRange("A1:M66").setValues(trainingRange); // passing the value to the created sheet
    }
  }
}
```

I also have a demo sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hKiyH_TA85-59jWUgI_E5oEXZToa2kROYZxxLcRxb7c/edit?usp=sharing).
Please tell me if this is what you wanted (if not can you give a demo sheet of what you want and what you should get at the end)

**EDIT**

here the script with formulas copy (it's not nice because you are forced to define in the script where your formulas are, we could have the script to analyse the spreadsheet to search the formulas, but, has it's a copy from template, it's less ressource consuming not to do so.)

```
function createWorkouts(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var nameSource = ss.getSheetByName("Maxes");
  var nameColumn = nameSource.getRange("A2:A").getValues(); // it's a table of table [][]

  var trainingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master Copy");
  var trainingRange = trainingSheet.getRange("A1:H21").getValues(); // get values give a table of table
  var trainingFormulasD = trainingSheet.getRange("D2:D21").getFormulas(); // get the formulas to copy
  var trainingFormulasH = trainingSheet.getRange("H2:H21").getFormulas(); // get others formulas to copy

  for(var i in nameColumn){ 
    if(nameColumn[i][0]!=""){ // if blank we skip
      try{ // try to see if already exist who know...
        var lifter = ss.getSheetByName(nameColumn[i][0]).activate();
        Logger.log("getting lifter sheet "+nameColumn[i][0]);
      }
      catch(err){ // well it didn't exist so lets create it :D
        var lifter = ss.insertSheet(nameColumn[i][0]);
        Logger.log("creating lifter sheet "+nameColumn[i][0]);
      }
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      lifter.getRange("A1:H21").setValues(trainingRange); // passing the value to the created sheet
      lifter.getRange("D2:D21").setFormulas(trainingFormulasD); //passing formulas
      lifter.getRange("H2:H21").setFormulas(trainingFormulasH); //passing formulas
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Harold I ran into a slight problem when I tried to run the code unfortunately it only copied the values on the page that I am using I have some formulas that I'd like copied as well. Do you have any suggestions on what I could change to make that work.

Comment: @kwalker66 unfortunately there is no easy way to do this in only one operation. what you need to do is to define where are your formulas (has you defined the range to copy) and copy them in the new sheet (I'll update my answer to show you...)

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help with this I updated using the information and ran it. It ran exactly as needed. Thanks again.